# Netty server and C# Socket Client. Receive on client doesn't work

Tags: c#, sockets, netty, tcpclient, protobuf-net

I want to receive message on C# client from Netty server. I use sync C# socket and protobuf.
I send message to server and it's ok. But I can't receive response.
Netty server uses ProtobufDecoder. Server ChannelInboundHandler has this part of code:

```
 public void channelRead0(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        ...
            Set<String> keys = jedis.keys("tanks*");

            String allKeys = "";
            for(String key: keys){
                allKeys+=key+";";
            }

            ctx.write(allKeys);
            ctx.flush();
}
```

C# client code is:

```
 const string server = "localhost";
const int port = 8080;
var tcpClient = new TcpClient(server, port);
_networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

var stream = new MemoryStream();
Serializer.Serialize(stream, tankDataObject);
var data = stream.ToArray();
_networkStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

data = new Byte[10000];

// String to store the response ASCII representation.
String responseData = String.Empty;

// Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
Int32 bytes = _networkStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);

// Close everything.
_networkStream.Close();
tcpClient.Close();
```

Client doesn't receive any bytes or receive empty array if I call ctx.close() on server. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: First of all I do not know anything about netty. So either the server is not sending, but if it is, it is probably because the client is too  early in reading data from the networkstream. Try putting a thread.sleep of 2 seconds or whatever the time the server needs, right after you have sent a message to the server as a test.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I've solved it. The solution was using obj in ctx.write(obj). In this case obj has msg object type but not string type. Shame of me!!! Obviously it's needed to add in channel pipeline ProtobufEncoder.

Comment: why do you not answer your own question with that?